# Is it safe to touch one terminal of a floating 20kV 1A PSU?

Tags: power-supply, safety

Yes, I know - stupid question, Darwin Award time... but, could someone get away with touching only one terminal of the floating PSU and not be seriously inconvenienced?

Comment: Could? maybe. Guaranteed? nope.

Comment: I wouldn't. Others might.

Comment: What is the best case scenario here?  Nothing happens?  Worst case is a fine pink mist.

Comment: if the floating supply was a 20kV battery on a poly chopping board, and I could see all round it, then I would. Anything that plugged in, I wouldn't trust to be sufficiently floating, even if you swore blind to me that it was.

Comment: I wouldn't touch anything in a 20 kW supply

Comment: @BryanBoettcher No, not a red mist. I know of someone who did touch such a supply, which was not "floating enough". Blew a chunk out of his hand and the muscle contraction broke his arm and several ribs when he hit a wall. Not to mention the burns. Long hospital stay.

Comment: @DirkBruere: then that wasn't the worst case, obviously :)

Comment: He won't be seriously inconvenienced, but his surviving relatives might be.

Answer (score 2):

Those of who who remember nylon shirts should remember that you got an electric shock every time you put one on or took one off. If you switched the lights down and closed the curtains you could even see little blue flashes as you wrestled with the electrostatic forces causing the shirt to cling to the skin. Thousands of volts were generated but the energy was low due to the capacitance being low.

If you have a 20 kV supply that is floating and powered from a battery (i.e. it is galvanically isolated) then there will be zero leakage to ground but there still could be some tens or even a hundred pico farads of capacitance that is charged up to 20 kV. I might be tempted to touch one of the floating leads if a nurse was on hand.

If on the other hand you have a 20 kV supply that is floating but powered via an isolating mains transformer, then capacitance to ground could be hundreds of pico farads and may even reach several nano farads. I wouldn't want to touch one of these.

Comment: _"If you have a 20 kV supply that is floating and powered from a battery (i.e. it is galvanically isolated) then there will be zero leakage to ground ..."_ - When you say "will", I think you mean "should".

Comment: **Amazing** video illustrating a lot more than a 20 kV float: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9tzga6qAaBA. Perhaps his "hot-suit" was nylon?

Comment: Nylon shirts aren't normally rated to provide 1 A.

Comment: @marcelm if it is galvanically isolated then there will be no leakage.

Answer (score 2):

The ONLY real answer is NO.

If the stars are all in alignment then theoretically you may get away with it but there are so many things that could go wrong it's simply NOT SAFE.

Apart from the other reasons given here you also have to think about what isolated means. Sure the positive and negative sides are separated by some insulator or maybe an air gap, but what does the presence of your body do to that insulation and isolation. Many folks have been electrocuted simply by getting a little too close where their body reduced the isolation to the point that an arc could form through the air and body and back..

This can especially be an issue if the live line is highly isolated and the neutral line not-so-much.

Bottom line... except under extreme and well understood and controlled conditions and procedures like the helicopter inspection someone showed in the video... stay well clear of high voltages.

Even when they are turned off, use a ground wire to make sure it's discharged BEFORE you touch it.